# Simple PHP Google Map integration using street address

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

So im trying to integrate a simple google map in my website where there is already a street and city in the database, what i want to do is when i echo these values that it shows a map.

I've already followed the instructions where i upload the Google map api and copy and pasted this code. im not sure what im doing wrong

```
<?php require(&quot;scripts/google_map_api/GoogleMapAPI.class.php&quot;);<br />
  <br />
  $map = new GoogleMapAPI('map');<br />
  <br />
  // enter YOUR Google Map Key<br />
  // ONLINE! $map-&gt;setAPIKey('myAPIKey');<br />
  $map-&gt;setAPIKey('myAPIKey');<br />
  $map-&gt;addMarkerByAddress('621 N 48th St # 6 Lincoln NE 68502','Our Address','&lt;b&gt;Our Address&lt;/b&gt;');<br />
</p>
<p> ?&gt;<br />
  <br />
  <?php $map-&gt;printMap(); ?>
```

am i missing something?

Comment: What Google map API is this? Any reason you don't want to send the results out as a JSON string and use the JS library instead on the client side?

Comment: im not sure what you mean, i just followed this site here - http://www.phpinsider.com/php/code/GoogleMapAPI/ i just want to display the map from the address that came from the database (e.g. street, city)

Comment: Generally Google maps is used using http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/ what HTML/JS does that bit of code produce? We need a little more information to help you out.

Comment: Are you using these two lines : <?php $map->printHeaderJS(); ?>
    <?php $map->printMapJS(); ?> ... I believe they are important to have the JS necessary to put the stuff on the map.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Amerra Connect SDK to show the map by searching a physical address. It requires just one line to call a function if you have the Amerra Connect SDK.

See [this post](http://doc.amerraconnect.com/?page_id=337) for more information.

For searching "45 Rockefeller Plaza, New York, NY 10111", you just need to call:

```html
<?php
 include("../lib/AmerraConnect.php");
 $amerraconnect = new AmerraConnect();
 echo $amerraconnect->showMap("45 Rockefeller Plaza, New York, NY 10111", "Rockefeller Center", "800", "800");
?>
```

For more information, visit http://www.amerraconnect.com.